# How to restructure the response of mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, response, project, httpresponse

I have an aggregation query as shown below

```
saveContacts(contactNumberList,req.body.vishReqBody.Contacts,req.body.vishReqHeader.AppId,req.body.vishReqBody.RegPhNo).then(function(user_data){
    users.find({PhNo:req.body.vishReqBody.RegPhNo},function(err,userDetails) {
        if (userDetails.length > 0){
            contacts.aggregate(
                [
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: "ProfileDetails",
                            localField: "PhNo",
                            foreignField: "PhNo",
                            as: "Profile_Details"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: "userDetails",
                            localField: "PhNo",
                            foreignField: "PhNo",
                            as: "user_Details"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $and: [
                                {PhNo: {$in: contactNumberList}},
                                {updatedbyAppid:  parseInt(req.body.vishReqHeader.AppId)},
                                {RegStatus:1}
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            "_id":0,
                            "Profile_Details._id":0,
                            "Profile_Details.__v":0,
                            "Profile_Details.Profile_Id":0,
                            "Profile_Details.Previous_Install_AppId":0,
                            "Profile_Details.Db_Updated_TimeStamp":0,
                            "Profile_Details.Db_Created_TimeStamp":0,
                            "user_Details.NsToken":0,
                            "user_Details._id":0,
                            "user_Details.__v":0,
                            "user_Details.Db_Created_TimeStamp":0,
                            "user_Details.Db_Updated_TimeStamp":0,
                            "user_Details.Profile_Id":0,
                            "profileId":0,
                            "PhNo":0,
                            "updatedbyAppid":0,
                            "RegStatus":0,
                            "Db_Updated_TimeStamp":0,
                            "Db_Created_TimeStamp":0,
                            "__v": 0,
                        }
                    }
                ],
                function (err, result) {
                    logger.info("upload contacts response");
                    logger.info(result)
                    if (result) {
                        res.send({
                            "result": {
                                "vishResHeader": {
                                    "ReqNo": req.body.vishReqHeader.reqNo,
                                    "ProcStatus": 0,
                                    "ErrCode": 0,
                                    "ErrMsgUsr": "",
                                    "serverTimeStamp": new Date().toISOString()
                                },
                                "vishResBody": {
                                    "Contacts": result
                                },
                                "vishResTrailer": {
                                    "Authentication": ""
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
        }
        else{
            res.send({
                "result": {
                    "vishResHeader": {
                        "ErrMsgUsr": "RegPhNo is not registered",
                        "ProcStatus": 0,
                        "ErrCode": 1
                    },
                    "vishResTrailer": {
                        "Authentication": ""
                    }
                }
            })
        }

    }, function(user_error){
        console.log(user_error);
        res.json({ error : user_error });

    });

})
```

The query returns the response in the following structure

```
"Contacts": [
                {
                    "PhoneBookName": "Cindy",
                    "Profile_Details": [
                        {
                            "AppId": 102,
                            "PhNo": "9538607847",
                            "Reg_Status": 1,
                            "ProfileName": "vishchat"
                        }
                    ],
                    "user_Details": [
                        {
                            "AppId": 100,
                            "GroupId": [
                                1
                            ],
                            "AttemptCnt": 1,
                            "Reg_Status": 1,
                            "PhNo": "9538607847",
                            "ProfileName": "vishchat"
                        },
                        {
                            "AppId": 102,
                            "GroupId": [
                                1
                            ],
                            "AttemptCnt": 1,
                            "Reg_Status": 1,
                            "PhNo": "9538607847",
                            "ProfileName": "vishchat"
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

the requirement is  to restructure the response in the following structure

```
"Contacts": [
                {
                    "PhoneBookName": "Cindy",
                    "user_Details": [
                        {
                            "AppId": 100,
                            "PhNo": "9538607847",
                            "Reg_Status": 1,
                            "ProfileName": "vishchat",
                            "AttemptCnt":1,
                            "GroupId": [
                                1
                            ],
                        }
                    ],

                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Should I make the changes in the `$project` of the query?

what is the difference between two response is the querying or should I use a for loop to restructure on the response but that will be process intense operation

Comment: Typo alert: it's a **query** - not a "qurie" ...

Comment: also the last sentence is messed up, please don't try to add 3 different questions into one.

Comment: before `$project` you might need to filter some nested documents

Comment: its only one question actually the last two are response of the query